# Need help about variable declaration in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I am studying VHDL for my degree and  I was asked to fix the error in this code, but after many tries I cannot manage to make it run. The compiler returns "Mem_Addr is used but not declared", highlighting the line that I mention below. I cannot manage to declare Mem_Addr properly.

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
LIBRARY altera_mf;
USE altera_mf.altera_mf_components.ALL;
ENTITY Ifetch IS
PORT( SIGNAL Instruction : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 31 DOWNTO 0 );
SIGNAL PC_plus_4_out : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
SIGNAL Add_result : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
SIGNAL Branch : IN STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL Zero : IN STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL PC_out : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 9 DOWNTO 0 );
SIGNAL clock, reset : IN STD_LOGIC);
END Ifetch;
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF Ifetch IS
SIGNAL PC, PC_plus_4 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 9 DOWNTO 0 );
SIGNAL next_PC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR( 7 DOWNTO 0 );
BEGIN
--ROM for Instruction Memory
data_memory: altsyncram
GENERIC MAP (
operation_mode => "ROM",
width_a => 32,
widthad_a => 8,
lpm_type => "altsyncram",
outdata_reg_a => "UNREGISTERED",
-- Reads in mif file for initial data memory values
init_file => "program.mif",
intended_device_family => "Cyclone")
-- Fetch next instruction from memory using PC
PORT MAP (
clock0 => clock,

-- ERROR HERE

address_a => Mem_Addr,

--

q_a => Instruction
);
-- Instructions always start on a word address - not byte
PC(1 DOWNTO 0) <= "00";
-- copy output signals - allows read inside module
PC_out <= PC;
PC_plus_4_out <= PC_plus_4;
-- send word address to inst. memory address register
Mem_Addr <= Next_PC;
-- Adder to increment PC by 4
PC_plus_4( 9 DOWNTO 2 ) <= PC( 9 DOWNTO 2 ) + 1;
PC_plus_4( 1 DOWNTO 0 ) <= "00";
-- Mux to select Branch Address or PC + 4
Next_PC <= X"00" WHEN Reset = '1' ELSE
Add_result WHEN ( ( Branch = '1' ) AND ( Zero = '1' ) )
ELSE PC_plus_4( 9 DOWNTO 2 );
-- Store PC in register and load next PC on clock edge
PROCESS
BEGIN
WAIT UNTIL ( clock'EVENT ) AND ( clock = '1' );
IF reset = '1' THEN
PC <= "0000000000" ;
ELSE
PC( 9 DOWNTO 2 ) <= Next_PC;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
END behavior;
```

Comment: The book Rapid Prototyping of Digital Systems: Quartus® II Edition has an [errata](http://hamblen.ece.gatech.edu/book/updatese.htm) not mentioning either error. The [CDROM source](http://hamblen.ece.gatech.edu/book/DE2booksoft.ZIP) (CHAP 14, IFETCH.VHD) declares `Mem_Addr`. `PC_plus_4_out <= PC_plus_4;` works because the output port `PC_plus_4` subtype indication is changed to (9 downto 0). The CDROM source code doesn't match the book text copied and pasted to the question from a PDF.

Comment: The missing declaration for `Mem_Addr` can be detected when at least the component declaration for `altsyncram` is provided. The lack of a matching element between the right hand expression and `PC_plus_4_out` requires either simulation or synthesis. Library `altera_mf` is not part of the VHDL standard and not provided other than with Altera/Intel Quartus tools.  That error would require the component declaration and `altsyncram` entity and architecture to qualify as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You're connecting the address port of the ram to a signal called mem_addr - only that signal does not exist because you didnt declare it.

You need something like this next to the other signals:

```
signal Mem_Addr : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
```

Comment: This change will allow the code to analyze and elaborate but not simulate nor synthesize. `PC_plus_4_out` has a subtype indication in OP code of `( 7 DOWNTO 0 )` while the subtype indication of `PC_plus_4` is `( 9 downto 0)`. The copied and pasted code from the book text PDF doesn't match the code from the accompanying CDROM (Chapter 14, IFETCH.VHD) which should simulate and synthesize).

Comment: I tried to run the CDROM version of this, runs for more time but I also get "Error (127001): Can't find Memory Initialization File or Hexadecimal (Intel-Format) File D:/Program Files/Quartus/Ifetch/program.mif for ROM instance ALTSYNCRAM" and "Error (12152): Can't elaborate user hierarchy "altsyncram:inst_memory|altsyncram_fnn3:auto_generated"  "

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in the Entity declaration the attributes 'SIGNAL' are unnecessary. Regarding your problem, you did not declare Mem_Addr signal. You have to declare it in the architecture :

```vhdl
architecture BEHAVIOR of ...
begin
  signal Mem_Addr : std_logic_vector(X downto 0);
```

Make sure to match X to the length-1 of the signal you connect it to (address_a)
Also, you have to drive the Mem_Addr signal with some signal carrying address values. Otherwise this signal will have undefined value, or be equal to the default value and will not impact the data memory.

So to fix this issue you have to find out if any signal in the Entity carries the address that you want to pass to the altsyncram memory or find out how to determine it based on the input signals of your component.